# Browser User Agent string with JSUA

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, user-agent

Visitors to our company web site have issues with the javascript we're serving. For any such javascript error, we get an email detailing the issue.

What is odd with these browsers are their user agent string. There are minor differences in the details, but in general they look like:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko (JSUA: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko)`

Am I right to say that it is an IE11 on Windows 7?

I've tried to figure out what the JSUA part means. Is it a browser run inside a javascript rendered container on a Media Center computer or what should I make of it?

Comment: http://www.useragentstring.com

Comment: Yes, but the site has about as much problems determining what the browser actually is, as I do. JSUA isn't explained. Regular IE11 browsers have no issues with our website, so something is broken in the browser identifying themselves as this.

Comment: Are the users actually reporting this themselves, or is this an automated error reporting system? The user agent string *looks* like IE11, but that doesn't mean it actually is IE11; it could be another browser or a bot spoofing the UA string.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think this user agent string is valid. Some token are duplicated:

```
Mozilla/5.0 
Windows NT 6.1 => Win7
Trident/7.0 => IE11
rv:11.0
```

and Microsoft had cleaned the user agent string with IE9. If you found there any .NET token, something is wrong and i would categorize this user agent string as a bot.